# Exporting In-House iOS app says certificate "Unknown", profile "none"?

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

I put together a test app simply to test In-House distribution through our Enterprise Developer Account.

Before archiving I checked that all signing settings looked good. Debug and Release show the correct provisioning profile and certificate.

Then I ARCHIVE the app. The prompts show this:

[image]

The correct cert and provisioning profile are shown. As the archive route continues I get to this screen:

[image]

I am trying to understand why it says: Certificate "Unknown" and Profile "None"

As I then try to distribute this through our MDM solution it never installs.

My question is: when distributing in-house enterprise apps, is it correct to see Certificate "Unknown" and Profile "None"?

Comment: I just wanted to report here that after testing, even though it says unknown and none like shown, the in house archive is actually created correctly. I am able to install the app on devices without problems. Is this just a UI bug then? I also inspected the provisioning profile in the app and it looks good. So, I am able to deploy the app without problems even with Xcode showing the screens I posted.

Comment: solved? how????

Comment: @grizzly I can see the confusion here. The UX in Xcode is misleading, it lead me to think that Xcode was the reason why the MDM install was not working. After days of troubleshooting the install problem turned out to be on my MDM server. So, Xcode is exporting the IN HOUSE app correctly even though the UX is not showing the proper signing UX like shown in the screenshots. This is solved because I have been able to prove on my end that it's just a UX problem. IN HOUSE exported apps still work fine for me regardless of the misleading Xcode UX.

Comment: i found issue. it is bug in xcode 10.1 and downgrade to xcode 10.0 and fix it. thank you

Comment: @grizzly by March 2019 you will be forced to use XCode 10.1 to submit '.ipa' versions to store

Comment: @MuhammadOmarElShourbagy yes, i known. thank you

Comment: @MuhammadOmarElShourbagy xcode 10.1 is bug for exporting. it write after finish signing: certificate and profile none (unknown). how to fix it? xcode 10.2 not releasing?

Comment: @grizzly many reported this issue and it is only UI/Display issue for XCode. if you continue the process and upload it it will work fine.

Comment: @MuhammadOmarElShourbagy no ui issue. it is real bug. app not install on device with xcode 10.1

Comment: @grizzly i submitted 2 versions of my app to store and it completed processing and being ready for sale

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have same behaviour: Apps validate and distribute fine, so I guess this is just a display issue introduced by XCode 10.1

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/338402#

Comment: that was splendid mAn!

Comment: For enterprise deployments, you can check the ExportOptions.plist and see that the certificate and provisioning profile are correct, confirming that it is just a UI bug.

Comment: @vignesh, how do you know that the app distributes just fine?

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue, only downgrade to Xcode 10.0 fixed it: [download old version of Xcode here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode)

Comment: Indeed, only a downgrade fix it for me as well

Comment: solve it. thanks.f**k apple, f**k xcode, f**k certificate, f**k appId, f**k identifier. king google and android :)

Comment: Downgrading is no solution since Apple is enforcing Xcode 10.1 from end of march 2019. 
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/

Comment: @Yuliwee, I appreciate you writing this. What is a solution then?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent whole today morning on it. I set certificate and profile but it showed None for both and app installation failed. I didn't fix None showing but fixed installation failing. In my case I've just remove string "Required device capabilities" from Info.plist. May be it helps you!

Comment: I removed it, but, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @zumzum i have same issue with xcode 10.1
so i try with "Application Loader" and that Work

- when you have failed dialog while upload app in app-store that time there is one more option to export build , just export and try to upload same build with  "Application Loader"