# "Over The Air" iOS App won't be complete download

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I've been trying to release a new version of some iOS App (developed with `React Native`) through the "Over The Air" way. I do have an Entreprise account. Also, I've done this before with the same App. It is the first time this fails.

The download of the app stops and looks like [image: this]

I've been investigating a lot and here are some informations I can give:

XCode: 10.1
React Native: 0.57.5
Deployment Target: 9.3

I recreated my certificate & provisioning profile. My signing profile looks like [image: this] which looks valid to me.

I'm downloading the app via a normal web page and the download link looks like this:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/path/to/the/manifest.plist">
  Download iOS
</a>
```

I'd like to release a build with an App Thinning `All compatible device variants`. The manifest looks normal to me but there is something that I question myself with. Prior to this release, in the manifest, the generated binaries looked like this: `MyApp-iPhone%207%20Plus-etc.ipa`. Now, since I updated `XCode` (from `10` to `10.1` if my memories are good) they look like this: `MyApp-0AB530E1-7309-4293-B4B6-C0AD90662766.ipa`.

I also verified the `App URL`, the `Display Image URL` and the `Full Size Image URL` and the three of them are valid.

Finally I checked the logs during the failing installation by going into `Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Open Console -> Errors and Failures`. Here are all the logs I could get telling me the installation failed. I've donc a couple research on Google but couldn't find nothing.

```
[PlaceholderUtility]: Failed artwork for bundleID: My.Bundle.Identifier error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=3 "Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible}
[PlaceholderUtility]: Failed to load placeholder artwork for bundleID: My.Bundle.Identifier error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=3 "Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible}
[ODRBackgroundMaintenance]: Cancelling maintenance operations.
[ODRLaunchServicesObserver]: Application My.Bundle.Identifier is invalid, ignoring the install notification from LaunchServicesLaunchServices reports My.Bundle.Identifier is not installed
Cannot generate canonicalExecutablePath for app <private> with no bundleExecutable set
LaunchServices reports My.Bundle.Identifier is not installed
asked question: p = <private>, q = <private>, e = 9 [<private>]
7 lines of: LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: <private>
Installation failed for <private>
8 lines of: LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: <private>
Applications did fail to install: ("<LSApplicationProxy: 0x10f438230> My.Bundle.Identifier file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/SOME_ID/MyApp.app <My.Bundle.Identifier <placeholder >:1>") (appInfos: (null))
LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: <private>
[LaunchServicesObserver]: Coordinator is already being observed: <IXInitiatingAppInstallCoordinator<0x100ef46f0> identifier:My.Bundle.Identifier uuid:SOME_UUID creator:App Store state:IXAppCoordinationStateErrorOccurred>
[CoordinatorStore]: <IXInitiatingAppInstallCoordinator<0x103e13ba0> identifier:My.Bundle.Identifier uuid:SOME_UUID creator:App Store state:IXAppCoordinationStateErrorOccurred> with UUID SOME_UUID was canceled with reason: Error Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app could not be installed at this time., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.RAz5m2/extracted/Payload/MyApp.app : 0xe800801c (No code signature found.), NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.RAz5m2/extracted/Payload/MyApp.app : 0xe800801c (No code signature found.), NSUnderlyingError=0x103eb7a90 {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/insta
!B21:My.Bundle.Identifier,J:-7761288138928876906#[<private>]: Fail temporarily for error: Error Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSLocalizedFailureReason=<private>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x103eb7a90 {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, LegacyErrorString=<private>, SourceFileLine=199, LibMISErrorNumber=-402620388, FunctionName=<private>}}}
[ProgressCache]: No progress exists for: My.Bundle.Identifier trying to begin anyway
```

Thanks in advance for the help.
Feel free to ask me questions for some infos I might have forgotten

Comment: have you got the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrading to XCode 10.0 fixed it.

As mentionned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112173/exporting-in-house-ios-app-says-certificate-unknown-profile-none), it seems that there is an issue with XCode 10.1 for this kind of build

Comment: so what is the solution to the problem above? I have used xcode 10.0 and it remains the same

Comment: Downgrading to XCode 10.0 fixed my issue. You probably have another issue that may look a bit the same